# Why is TableRow not hoverable in Grommet?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, grommet

I'm using grommet to develop an app. A bunch of the components in the library have an onClick prop and when you supply a callback function to the onClick prop of a component it becomes hoverable. But this doesn't seem to happen for the TableRow component. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/79491/). It shouldbn't be too difficult to fix this with some css but I'm wondering if it's some design concept that I'm missing out on(i.e. A reason why TableRows in particular are not hoverable) or if there's a more grommet-esque to make TableRows hoverable.

Code:

index.html:

```
<script src="https://facebook.github.io/react/js/jsfiddle-integration-babel.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <!-- This element's contents will be replaced with your component. -->
</div>
```

index.js:

```
var Box = Grommet.Box;
var Table = Grommet.Table;
var TableRow = Grommet.TableRow;
var TableHeader = Grommet.TableHeader;

const NotHoverable = () => {

let data = [{"name": "John", "title": "Developer", "city": "Dublin"},
            {"name": "Paul", "title": "Architect", "city": "Bristol"},
            {"name": "Mary", "title": "CTO", "city": "Berlin"},
            {"name": "Frank", "title": "Ops", "city": "New York"},
            {"name": "Jane", "title": "HR", "city": "Tokyo"}]

  return (
    <Box pad='small'>
      <Table>
        <TableHeader labels={["name", "title", "city"]} />
        <tbody>
          {data.map( (component, index) => 
            <TableRow onClick={() => console.log('Row Clicked!')} style={{"borderBottom": "1px solid"}} >
              <td>
                {component.name}
              </td>
              <td>
                {component.title}
              </td>
              <td>
                {component.city}
              </td>
            </TableRow>
          )}
        </tbody>
      </Table>
    </Box>
  )
}

const Hoverable = () => 
  <Box colorIndex={'grey-1'} onClick={() => console.log('Box clicked')}>
    Hoverable Box
  </Box>

ReactDOM.render(
  <Box>
    <NotHoverable />
    <hr />
    <Hoverable />
  </Box>,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Grommet is designed with a mobile-first, or at least mobile-friendly, philosophy.

While a click is broadly equivalent to a tap, a mouse hover has no analogue on a touch device. `onClick` is almost a misnomer, as it comes from an abstract JavaScript-y way of thinking about it - many components have `onActive` or `onSelect` handlers instead.

As you've noted yourself, it's fairly easy to remedy this with some CSS or SCSS - just keep in mind mobile users will never see it. :)